# Find eigenvalues of huge matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a huge matrix (7,000,000 x 7,000,000). It is singular sparse Laplacian matrix.
I am looking for algorithm to find eigenvalues. I need to find the second eigenvalue (the first one is zero)

Python and matlab functions are not working because of the matrix size... any help will be appreciated...

Comment: You are more likely to get a useful answer for this on Cross Validated SE, http://stats.stackexchange.com Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

ARPACK should help. Or any of the related ages-old packages for linear algebra with sparse matrix support.

If you only need the second eigenvalue, a simple inverse iteration can also do the trick (I don't know if you want the second smallest or second largest). You can do this in matlab, sparse matrix multiplication should work there. The algorithm is absurdly simple:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_iteration

Comment: I am looking for second smallest eigenvalue... inverse iteration is not working since the matrix is singular (or too close to singular)

Comment: It should work if the initial approximation of the eigenvalue is not zero. $A-\lambda I$ is not singular, even if $A$ is. If you get close enough, it converges precisely because $A-\lambda I$ is *becoming* singular, and the magnitude of the eigenvector is getting very big.